# row dependant variables in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql database as follows. I am using it with phpmyadmin.

```
id time_came time_exit
  0      2         3   
  1      3         5   
  5      5         1   
  7      1         10   
  9      1         8
```

I want another column as "wait" with the following logic,

```
foreach(i in time_came){
   wait=count(time_came<i&&i<time_exit)
}
```

So then each column has a "wait" value too. I can do this with php. But I need to do this with mysql. I am confusing because "i" is varying for each row?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I love pseudo-code. It makes me want to give an equal pseudo-answer.

Comment: Will be great if you have an answer for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t2
        where t2.time_came between t.time_came and t2.time_came < t.time_exit
       ) as wait
from table t;
```

EDIT:

To do the update, you need to use `join`:

```
update table t join
       (select t.id,
               (select count(*)
                from table t2
                where t2.time_came between t.time_came and t2.time_came < t.time_exit
               ) as wait
        from table t
       ) as newval
       on t.id = newval.id
    set t.wait = newval.wait
```

Comment: Thank you. What is "t2"? Think "t" is the existing table?

Comment: It is a table alias and needed for a correlated subquery.  Put your table name where `table` is (you don't specify it in the question).

Comment: Perfect. This is working great. How can I learn to make such queries? :)

Comment: How can I make this to update the column wait? eg: update myTable set 'wait'=[what to put there] ?